In LWC, how to put up spinner while long running Apex method runs
I want to put up a spinner while a long-running operation runs when a button is pressed.  I try conditionally rendering via a member variable set in them method that handles the button without success.  I suspect that's because the change to the value in is not evaluated until the method returns and it doesn't return until the work completes.
Portion of html.
...
  <template if:true={showSpinner}>
      <section aria-modal="true" class="slds-modal slds-fade-in-open">
          <div class="slds-modal__container ">
              <header class="slds-modal__header">
                  <h2 class="slds-text-heading_small">Doing Stuff</h2>
              </header>
              <div class="slds-modal__content modalBody">
                  <lightning-spinner alternative-text="Doing Stuff" size="large" class="spinnerClass"></lightning-spinner>
                  <div class="slds-p-around_small">
                      <p>We be doing stuff ...</p>
                  </div>
              </div>
              <footer class="slds-modal__footer">
              </footer>
          </div>
      </section>
      <div class="slds-backdrop slds-backdrop_open"></div>
  </template>  
...

Portion of .js
handleSubmit() {
  this.showSpinner = true;
  callLongRunnigApexMethod();
  .then((result) => {    
    // TBD handle success.
  })
  .catch((ex) => {
    // TBD handle success.
  });
  this.showSpinner = false;
}

If the cause is what I suspect, then I somehow have to fire and forget the method that does the work so the handle method returns right away.  I tried running an inner method declared async but that didn't appear to change behavior.  I ran it in a debugger and it appears that the inner method declared async still ran synchronously.
handleSubmit() {
  this.showSpinner = true;
  doWork();
  this.showSpinner = false;
}

async doWork() {
  callLongRunnigApexMethod()
  .then((result) => {    
    // TBD handle success.
  })
  .catch((ex) => {
    // TBD handle success.
  });
}

The component is itself is launched as a modal and I thought that might be related to the issue.  Here's the entire html...
<template>
    <lightning-modal-header label={headerLabel}></lightning-modal-header>
    <lightning-modal-body>
        <span>{messageText}</span>
        <template lwc:if={showSpinner}> THIS IS A TEST.  SHOULDN'T THIS SHOW?
            <section aria-modal="true" class="slds-modal slds-fade-in-open">
                <div class="slds-modal__container ">
                    <header class="slds-modal__header">
                        <h2 class="slds-text-heading_small">DoingWork</h2>
                    </header>
                    <div class="slds-modal__content modalBody">
                        <lightning-spinner alternative-text="DoingWork meeting" size="large" class="spinnerClass"></lightning-spinner>
                        <div class="slds-p-around_small">
                            <p>DoingWork meeting ...</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <footer class="slds-modal__footer">
                    </footer>
                </div>
            </section>
            <div class="slds-backdrop slds-backdrop_open"></div>
        </template>        
    </lightning-modal-body>
    <lightning-modal-footer>
        <div class="slds-m-top_small slds-align_absolute-center">
            <lightning-button 
                variant="Neutral" 
                label="Cancel" 
                class="slds-m-left_x-small" 
                onclick={handleCancel}>
            </lightning-button>
            <lightning-button 
                variant="brand" 
                class="slds-m-left_x-small" 
                label={confirmLabel} 
                onclick={handleConfirm}>
            </lightning-button>
        </div>
    </lightning-modal-footer>        
</template>


I should mention that this code is in a modal launched from another component.  I'm wondering if that has something to do with it.  I have other components where I change variables that control conditionally rendering templates within the html and the work without issue.

You can change your js to handle this scenario.
handleSubmit() {
  this.showSpinner = true;
  callLongRunnigApexMethod();
  .then((result) => {    
    // TBD handle success.
  })
  .catch((ex) => {
    // TBD handle success. 
  }).finally(()= >{
    this.showSpinner = false;
  })
  
}

If you are calling an apex method then to show and hide functionality you need to handle in then and catch block.
How js work is it will execute the  callLongRunnigApexMethod() and will not wait for then and catch part of code to work. These are like callback functions which will execute once apex returns any response.
Right now flow of your code is

set Spinner true
Call apex
set Spinner false
then wait for apex response
then call then or catch based on response.

But if you move set spinner false in then and catch block then your code will work fine.
Also i think you can use Lightning-spinner component directly in code.

Turning the spinner off in a finally ensures it is always turned off (including when an exception is thrown in the catch) and IMO is easier to understand.

The issue was indeed that that spinner was being set on but that it was immediately set to false. The set to false can go either in both the then and the catch or in a finally.  I suppose it's better programming to put it in a finally as the same line isn't coded twice.

yes @ken using finally will be correct. If this answer solved your issue you can mark it as correct response.

I think what you want to do is to bind the value controlling your spinner rendering behind a getter. This is because the getters are called every render cycle.
showSpinner = false;
get displaySpinner(){
   return this.showSpinner;  
}
handleButtonClick(){
   this.showSpinner = true;
   // do Apex  
}


Don't think that's needed, moving showSpinner = false ot the then and catch or putting it in a finally resolves the issue.
